# XCODE: fail to send signal

Tags: c, xcode

I am simulating a signal handler program with Xcode.
How can I deliver signal in console?

```
(lldb) process handle -p1 -s0 SIGINT
NAME         PASS   STOP   NOTIFY
===========  =====  =====  ======
SIGINT       true   false  true 
(lldb) process signal SIGINT
error: Failed to send signal 2: failed to send signal 2
(lldb)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy-paste the actual text (as text) into the question body instead. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Also, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without a MCVE it's really impossible to say what you're doing and what the problem might be.

Comment: Lastly, when the system functions fail you should check `errno` to see what the error is. Consider using `strerror` to translate the error code to a printable string.

Comment: Thanks. But i am trying to simulate Ctrl+C in the xcode